# Replace username by billing first name in Woocommerce checkout registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, account

I've tried to replace username with first name billing using the code below [changed from this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516597/username-auto-generated-by-billing-complete-name-in-woocommerce-registration/45528245#45528245), but keep getting 500 error.

If I use first and last name it works but I would prefer to use first name only.

Code is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'custom_new_customer_data', 10, 1 );
function custom_new_customer_data( $new_customer_data ){

    // Complete HERE in this array the wrong usernames you want to replace (coma separated strings)
    $wrong_user_names = array( 'info', 'contact' );

    // get the first billing name
    if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];

    if( ( ! empty($first_name) ) ) && in_array( $new_customer_data['user_login'], $wrong_user_names ) ){

        // the customer billing complete name
        $first_name = $first_name;

        // Replacing 'user_login' in the user data array, before data is inserted
        $new_customer_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user( str_replace( $first_name ) );
    }
    return $new_customer_data;
}
```

My question would be, how would I configure WooCommerce to generate the username by the custom fields: First Name (billing_first_name) instead of full name or username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, to replace username by the billing firstname during checkout registration:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'customer_username_based_on_firstname', 20, 1 );
function customer_username_based_on_firstname( $new_customer_data ){

    // Complete HERE in this array the wrong usernames you want to replace (coma separated strings)
    $wrong_user_names = array( 'info', 'contact' );

    // get the first billing name
    if(isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];

    if( ! empty($first_name) && ! in_array( $_POST['billing_first_name'], $wrong_user_names ) ){

        // Replacing 'user_login' in the user data array, before data is inserted
        $new_customer_data['user_login'] = sanitize_user( $first_name );
    }
    return $new_customer_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Your error was coming from `str_replace( $first_name )`. This php function needs 3 arguments.