# Woocommerce - Edit account issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My Woocommerce is setup to generate username automatically. I'm trying to use the code below to change username before save. I would like to change user name to be equal a custom field filled in billing form.

My code is:

```
function wc_cpf_as_username ( $user_login ) {

        if( !empty($_POST['billing_cpf'] ) ) {
            $user_login = $_POST['billing_cpf'];
        }

        elseif (!empty( $_POST['billing_cnpj'] )){
            $user_login = $_POST['billing_cnpj'];
        }

        else{
            $user_login = $_POST['billing_email'];
        }

    return $user_login;     

}

add_filter( 'pre_user_login' , 'wc_cpf_as_username' );
```

The code work to create user, but this code do not work to edit user in my account page (/my-account/edit-account). Woocommerce show success message (Account details changed successfully.), but data is not changed.

I do not know what is the issue.

Could you help me?

Comment: Check it, please - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update

Comment: Hello, I am using this hook because I need create my username with custom field value. The hook edit_user_profile_update work only to edit user. I did not find a hook that work only to create user. But I would like to know why Woocommerce edit account isn't working with this code. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are making that complex function if you have a hook available for this. `edit_user_profile_update` hook i.e. located in `/wp-admin/user-edit.php`.

`update_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_meta_key', $_POST['custom_meta_key'])`.

`update_user_meta` thats for update user meta field based on user ID.

```
 add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');


     function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
         if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )
             update_user_meta($user_id, 'Custom_field', $_POST['your_field']);
     }
```

Comment: Hello, I am using this hook because I need create my username with custom field value. The hook edit_user_profile_update work only to edit user. I did not find a hook that work only to create user. But I would like to know why Woocommerce edit account isn't working with this code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you said! you want to change username to a custom field filled in the billing form. I think you want to generate the username by the custom fields: First Name and Last Name? am I right?

Comment: If this the case check this thread.
I hope it helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516597/username-auto-generated-by-billing-complete-name-in-woocommerce-registration

Comment: this url was helpfull, the hook **woocommerce_new_customer_data** working fine for my purpose, thank you!